# Mat Stepper does not go to next step when condition is met

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-stepper

I have 3 components, a mat-horizontal-stepper, component A and component B. Both components are called into the stepper. I want to navigate from component A to component B under the requirement that condition C is met. Condition C is implemented in a method called pay() and called in a button. pay() is a method that makes a payment and if the payment is successful , it should navigate to step 2 otherwise if payment is unsuccessful, it should remain on step 1.

Issue : when condition C is met, that is, payment is successful. I am not able to navigate to step 2.

See my code below

Component A  ts file

```
@ViewChild(MatStepper) stepper!: MatStepper;

pay() {
 if(payment === "success"){
     this.goToNextStep()
   }
  else{
   console.warn("error")
 }

  goToNextStep() {
    console.log('Going to the next step...');
       if (this.stepper) {
      this.stepper.next();
   }
  }
```

Component A html file

```
<button (click)="pay()">
go to step 2 when payment is successful
<button>
```

Component B html file

```
payment successful
```

Stepper html file

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper [linear]="true">
 <mat-step>
 <app-component-a></app-component-a>
 </mat-step>

 <mat-step>
 <app-component-b></app-component-b>
 </mat-step>

</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Comment: Create a full functional example in stackblitz for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component A doesn't have access to the stepper in it's parent component.
`this.stepper` will always be `undefined`.

Component A should emit an event and then you can call `this.stepper.next();` from it's parent or you can add an `@Input` to Component A and pass the stepper as an input.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have applied what you have said and both suggestions are working.  Since you did not provide any snippets, I will post the updated snippets in another answer so that others can benefit and I will tag you.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 provided by @Zerotwelve

```html
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-a',
  template: `
    <button (click)="pay()">Go to step 2 when payment is successful</button>
  `
})
export class ComponentA {
  @Output() paymentSuccess: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

  pay() {
    if (payment === 'success') {
      this.paymentSuccess.emit();
    } else {
      console.warn('Payment error');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper [linear]="true">
  <mat-step>
    <app-component-a (paymentSuccess)="goToNextStep()"></app-component-a>
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step>
    <app-component-b></app-component-b>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

```html
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material/stepper';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stepper',
  templateUrl: './stepper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stepper.component.css']
})
export class StepperComponent {
  @ViewChild(MatStepper) stepper!: MatStepper;

  goToNextStep() {
    console.log('Going to the next step...');
    if (this.stepper) {
      this.stepper.next();
    }
  }
}
```

Solution 2 provided by @Zerotwelve

```html
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-a',
  template: `
    <button (click)="pay()">Go to step 2 when payment is successful</button>
  `
})
export class ComponentA {
  @Input() stepper: MatStepper | undefined;

  pay() {
    if (payment === 'success' && this.stepper) {
      this.stepper.next();
    } else {
      console.warn('Payment error');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper [linear]="true">
  <mat-step>
    <app-component-a [stepper]="stepper"></app-component-a>
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step>
    <app-component-b></app-component-b>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Comment: thank you for sharing the code. Btw I would prefer the first solution since it's more clean. Component-a doesn't need to know anything about the stepper and it's more reusable.

Comment: thanks for mentioning that. I was going with second solution since the code is shorter but much thanks for highlighting that component does need to know anything about the stepper, and it is more reusable. This adheres to SOLID principles